# Getting unique record group with more than one rows

Tags: mysql

I have the following table in MySQL:

Table Scores:

```
id integer
score integer
scoredate date
```

composite (id,scoredate) is unique

```
id  score scoredate
--+----+------
1 | 2 | 2015-01-01
1 | 2 | 2015-01-02
1 | 3 | 2015-01-03
1 | 2 | 2015-01-04   
2 | 3 | 2015-01-01
2 | 3 | 2015-01-02
2 | 3 | 2015-01-03
2 | 3 | 2015-01-04
3 | 1 | 2015-01-01
3 | 1 | 2015-01-02
3 | 1 | 2015-01-03
3 | 1 | 2015-01-04
4 | 3 | 2015-01-01
4 | 3 | 2015-01-02
4 | 3 | 2015-01-03
4 | 1 | 2015-01-04
```

I want to identify 'ids' whose scores changed at least once.

```
id  score
--+----
1 | 2 
1 | 3 
4 | 3 
4 | 1
```

I am able to do this using a complex subquery but I was wondering if there was a way to do it using a simpler query.

For example the with following query I get the id's that we care about. I could do another subquery or join with this the output of this to get the result above but I was hoping to build a simpler query. The following is already effectively 2 passes (2 queries) and doing another join or subquery with this means a 3rd pass or query to be processed by the engine:

```
SELECT `id` FROM (SELECT `id`, `score` FROM `scores` GROUP BY `id`, `score`) AS sq GROUP BY `id` HAVING count(1) > 1
```

I am hoping to get to the result in 1-2 passes/ queries.

Comment: Yes, there is. What did you try already? (GROUP BY and HAVING not required)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct id, score
FROM Scores
where id in (select id from Scores group by id having count(distinct score) > 1);
```

This would give you the result you wanted.

Comment: I suspect that this is along the lines of what the OP had already, but we don't really know.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.*
           FROM my_table x
           JOIN my_table y
             ON y.id = x.id
            AND y.date > x.date
            AND y.score <> x.score;
```